# How to Improve my Computer Architecutre and Design skills?

Tags: spi, computer-architecture, sram, reference-materials

Though my undergraduation was in Computer Science but I like to believe that I am more of an embedded systems enthusiast and I am comfortable in reading datasheets and timing diagrams. But this was before my Master’s course- computer architecture and design midterm, it was quite evident from my attempts that I was not clear with the basics. 
In hindsight, my attempts in the midterm was basically laughable. **E.g.** I was trying to design a 4 bit counter without actually creating a truth table. I also sent a 8 bit data to a 4X16 bit SRAM using SPI. 
Since then,  I am doubting my concepts in this subject and want to improve.

So basically, my question to the community is- how can I better myself in the design and computer architecture(low level) skills.

I really want to improve but I dont know where to start.

Comment: A great question, but in the wrong place. This is not a good question for Stack Exchange, it's too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: I found this to be quite fun http://www.nand2tetris.org

Comment: Get a PDF of the 1974 Texas Instruments TTL Data Handbook. And read it.

Answer (score 2):

Get an Arduino board, or one of the cheap demo boards such as the STM32 series, and program it from the ground up using just the data manuals and C/Assembler. Nothing beats actually doing a real project.